# How to use auth middlware in livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I trying to use middleware but it seems not to work.I Want to prevent direct access of components via url. am using the auth

```
    Route::get('/', \App\Http\Livewire\Login::class)->name('login');
Route::get('/login', \App\Http\Livewire\Login::class)->name('login');
Route::get('analytics',\App\Http\Livewire\Analytics::class)->name('analytics')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('members',\App\Http\Livewire\Members::class)->name('members')->middleware('auth');;
```

Here is my login component.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;


class Login extends Component
{

    public $user;

    public function mount(){
    }
    public function login(){
        return redirect()->route('analytics');
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your login component doesn't actually log anyone in.  And when you say "doesn't work", that's very vague. Doesn't work *how*? What happens, what fails?

Comment: Users have not direct access to your component unless using it in a view. so try to prevent user access using a middleware on routes that you have defined.